# Playwright test works fine localy, but fails in pipeline

Tags: testing, pipeline, playwright, cicd

I am trying to run this code:

```
test('should login', async ({ page }) => {
await page.goto(localhost);
await page.fill('[name=username]', 'username');
await page.fill('[name=password]', 'password');
await page.click('[name=login]');
await page.waitForURL(`${localhost}/main`);
const currentUrl = await page.url();
expect(currentUrl).toBe(`${localhost}/main`);
});
```

When I run it with `npx playwright test` localy, the test passes; but, when run in CI/CD, it fails:

```
Timeout of 180000ms exceeded.
page.waitForURL: Navigation failed because page was closed!
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for navigation to "http://localhost:3000/main" until "load"
============================================================
```

Any idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would try logging all network requests to see what's going on there:

```js
// Log and continue all network requests
  page.route('**', (route, request) => {
    console.log(request.url());
    route.continue();
});
```

If it never gets beyond the `goto()`, perhaps try using the new playwright request [fixture](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-get) to see if it can even reach `http://localhost:3000/main`.

```js
await page.request.get("http://localhost:3000/main", { ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
```

Comment: So the problem was that when i ran the test localy, i was connected to the backend thanks to VPN. However CI/CD doesnt have any way to connect to BE and the page never gets from login to main page.

Comment: @TomášHrubý did you solve this? i'm currently having this issue